# EBML serialization performance and existing library in JAVA

Tags: java, xml, web-services, binary-xml

Currently exploring ways to improve the performance on rather traditional SOAP web services processing chain, I'm looking toward binary XML and especially EBML.

First simple question: is there any reference performance evaluation comparing XML and EBML (or other binary XML alternative)? The goal of such change is obviously to boost serialization, transmission and parsing, but my (rather short) searches did not point out any benchmark.

Second follow up question: is there existing reliable open source implementation of binary XML in JAVA?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some Java implementation here : https://github.com/Matroska-Org/jebml but didn't use it by myself.